# FHSTwitterEngine get stored account

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter, fhs-twitter-engine

I use FHSTwitterEngine for twitting from my app. I know i can use XAuth and OAuth to login twitter account, but I'm wondering if is there any way to login by getting Twitter account assigned to iPhone. I mean that I can assign my twitter account in setting in my iPhone and some app get this stored data from settings and can login user basis on it. Is this feature avaiable under FHSTwitterEngine?

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't require/import `Social.framework` or similar, `FHSTwitterEngine` does not support iOS Twitter accounts.

`Social.framework` allows posting to twitter/facebook, but does not offer any information like OAuth tokens to log in outside of it.